# unity rotation difference and direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I would like to know the rotation difference between two objects on one Axis, like for example on Y axis.

I tried using Quaternion.Angle but it calculate whole rotation, not on one axis

using

> angle=transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y-target.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;

works,
however this does not tell me the target's direction compared to me, how many angles to the left or to the right?

edit:
no it doesn't work, it only works if both transforms' x and z rotation axis is 0.

If, for example I put both start rotation at (349.8176,113.8314,254.5617) 
,then I rotate the target 3 degrees to its right, it became (352.7103,113.0266,254.684), which will return an Y angle difference of 0.8 instead of 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the scalar product between the forward vectors to determine if they both face in the same direction or look at (or away from) each other:

```
float dot = Vector3.Dot( transform.forward, target.transform.forward );
bool sameDirection = dot >= 0;
```

You could even use vector math to compute the angle without to roll out the huge quaternion canon:

```
// align forward vectors to the XZ plane / Y axis first
Vector3 sourceForward = transform.forward;
Vector3.OrthoNormalize( Vector3.up, ref sourceForward );
Vector3 targetForward = target.transform.forward;
Vector3.OrthoNormalize( Vector3.up, ref targetForward );

// get the angle between both transforms arount the Y axis
float dot = Vector3.Dot( sourceForward, targetForward );
float angleRad = Mathf.Acos( dot );
float angleDeg = Mathf.Rad2Deg( angleRad );

// see if the angle is clockwise or counter-clockwise
Vector3 up = Vector3.Cross( sourceForward, targetForward );
angleDeg = up.y < 0 ? -angleDeg : +angleDeg;
```

***Disclaimer***: This all is purely theoretical because I have no possibility to test this with Unity 3D at the moment.

Comment: slick! This one works, thank! However, if the objects x rotation is over 90 degrees, the sign of angleDeg is flipped

Answer (score 0):

For the direction use this:

```
Vector3 offset =  transform.position - target.position;
```

Comment: ah no, my mean of direction is the rotation direction. For example object A is 30 degree and object B is 60 degree, that would mean object B is 30 degree to the right.

Comment: your code return to you what you want, the difference rotation from A to B.
Right or left side is with signed. I.e: if A is 60 and B is 30 you got -30

Comment: because, strangely, if both object start rotation is 0,0,0 then the rotation difference (0-330/0-30) would be -330 and -30 instead of -30/+30

Comment: I just test with 2 objects in diferents rotations, and positions and too with 0,0,0 and i got right difference: 0,0,0.

Comment: Can you tell me what you like to do finally with this rotation difference?

Comment: It's going to be like a turret on top of a body or something.
if the body is at 0,0,0 rotation and turret is 0,30,0/0,330,0 rotation, using 

angle=transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y-target.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;

the rotation difference is -330/-30 instead of -30/+30.
I wanted so that the bigger the angle difference, the faster the body turns

Comment: You can handle this without the angle distance. When you make the rotation with a tween or rotate you use a time value for the transition and is usefull too a speed value.
But is you only like that all rotations spent same time (minor rotation go slowly than bigger rotation) use only a time value.  
`transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards (transform.rotation, target.rotation, Time.deltaTime);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards (transform.rotation, target.rotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);`